# Unit testing extension methods, had a go, is this right, or gone around the houses?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have my POCO library and i have entities that implement an interface called IEntityDelete.

Interface is very simple, looks something like this

```
public interface IEntityDelete 
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

So i have an entity that implements this interface, again very simple, looks something like this

```
public class MyEntity() : IEntityDelete
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I have an extension method, which i created this like

```
public static void MarkAsDeleted(this IEntityDelete entity)
{
    entity.IsDeleted = true;
}
```

Then i needed to check if this method was being called within one of my service methods in my unit tests.  Service method is very basic, looks something like this.

```
public Task<int> DeleteByFlagAsync(MyEntity entity)
{
    entity.MarkAsDeleted();

    return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Apparently you cannot test extension methods easily, without using Microsofts Moles framework, but i do not want another dependency.

I did some googl'ing and found 2 articles on this, and how to do about it, and would like to know if this is correct, or whether i have done something stupid.

Two articles i found where

> http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html
>   http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-mock-extension-methods/

They recommend using a wrapper class which aint static, so i ended up with this.

First created my wrapper interface

```
public interface IEntityDeleteWrapper 
{
    void MarkAsDeleted(IEntityDelete entity);
}
```

Create a class that implements this interface

```
public class EntityDeleteWrapper : IEntityDeleteWrapper
{
    public void MarkAsDeleted(IEntityDelete entity)
    {
        entity.IsDeleted = true;
        entity.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.DeletedByUserId = 546372819;
    }
}
```

Inject this interface into my service constructor

```
public MyService(IEntityDeleteWrapper deleteWrapper)
{
    _deleteWrapper = deleteWrapper;
}
```

Change my service method call to use the wrapper like so

```
public Task<int> DeleteByFlagAsync(MyEntity entity)
{
    _deleteWrapper.MarkAsDeleted(entity);

    return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**SOLVED**
As i was told, this was way too far to go, i can just check if a property has changed.  In light of this, i am using my extension method still and updated my unit test to this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void should_mark_entity_as_deleted()
{
    // arrange
    var entity = new Attachment
    {
        IsDeleted = false
    };

    // act
    var result = _service.DeleteByFlagAsync(entity).Result;

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, entity.IsDeleted);
    _context.Verify(e => e.SaveChangesAsync(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to check the extension method was being called? It looks like you really want to test `DeleteByFlagAsync` and in that case it doesn't matter how it marks the entity as deleted. You can easily test `MarkAsDeleted` by checking `entity.IsDeleted` is `true` after calling it.

Comment: but shouldnt i have a test that specifically tests that MarkAsDeleted is setting IsDeleted = true?  Therefore, in DeleteByFlagAsync, i just need to know if the method is being called?

Comment: And this is a simplified version as well

Comment: You don't need to know that `MarkAsDeleted` was called, just that the entity was deleted which you can do by either just checking `IsDeleted` or querying the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went too far. Your test should verify *observable change to state*, not how that change was made. Otherwise you make your tests very brittle, not to mention you add rather unnecessary extra layer. It would be enough to check whether entity properties changed after `DeleteByFlagAsync` call.

Of course, when deleting gets more complex introducing dependency to delegate this task to makes sense. But then, few questions arise:

- What would be the scope of `DeleteByFlagAsync`? Call two dependencies?
- Would it be practical to test it?
- ...or perhaps tests for said dependency would suffice (as this is where the actual *mark-for-deletion* will take place)?

Comment: Sorry, very new to unit testing, so trying to do it correctly, thus why i thought i would ask. So should the test for DeleteByFlagAsync only test that the object has changed?  Not if SaveChangesAsync has been called either?  I do not want to connect to a database for my unit tests, so i have mocked my DbContext for this.

Comment: Edited my unit test, are you saying this is enough for a unit test?

Comment: Your *unit* here is that entity was deleted. That's what this method does. To verify that, you need to check that a) flag was flipped, b) call to context was made. These two things make up this method. If deletion is more than flipping some bool you might consider having two separate tests, 1) entity was prepared for deletion (verify properties) 2) context was saved (verify mocked context call).

Comment: thanks a lot for guidance.  Obviously i am over thinking when it comes to unit testing, and need to keep it simple.  I have updated my unit test to check the flag and context was saved.